# existence of Riemann metric on smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be the smooth manifold,prove there exist some Riemann metric on it.

This is the standard application of partition of unity thoerem:First find the local $g_\alpha$ on each chart by pullback the standard metric on Euclidean space.

since the chart of the manifold covers $M$,appling partition of unity to glue those $g_\alpha$ togother as :

$$g = \sum\rho_\alpha g_\alpha$$

To prove it's a Riemann metric,we need to check two things :

first it's smooth,second at each point it satisfy the inner product axioms.

Here is a bit detail that confuses me is how to define $g_\alpha$ outside original domain $U_\alpha$?It may depend on the existence of smooth extension of $g_\alpha$ outside $U_\alpha$.Does this result holds?To make it more clear I make the proposition below:

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold,prove given closed subset $A \subset M$,and a smooth tensor field on $A$ ,there exist a smooth extension of this tensor field to $M$.

Comment: If you insist on extending $g_\alpha$ before writing the sum $\sum \rho_\alpha g_\alpha$, then just take $g_\alpha = 0$ outside $U_\alpha$. The possible discontinuity at $U_\alpha$ doesn't matter at all, since $\rho_\alpha g_\alpha$ doesn't depend on the extension.

Comment: thanks,I find a way to make it rigor,first just take product of function $\rho_\alpha g_\alpha$ on $U$ (which is smooth) then take zero extension of it,which is smooth by gluing lemma.The idea is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter because $\rho_\alpha$ is supported on $U_\alpha$, which means that $\rho_\alpha g_\alpha$ is zero outside $U_\alpha$.

Comment: if exist a smooth extension no matter which value outside $U_\alpha$ it always behave well as the POU support on $U_\alpha$,the point it does smooth extension exist ?This may similar to the result for smooth function